# What is the Twisted Essence of Suffering used for?

Tags: diablo-ii

2 of these was dropped after fighting Andariel in Hell Difficulty, they can't be traded or sold, what are they used for?

Presumably some Hordadric Cube recipe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct that it is a horadric cube recipe. It creates a Token of Absolution that allows you to respec. a character.

> Added in Patch 1.13, the Token of Absolution is a consumable item that
>   grants the character one stat/skill reset. This works in the same way
>   as the reward from the Den of Evil quest, but allows a character
>   infinite respecs, provided that they are willing to gather the
>   reagents each time they desire a respec. The Token of Absolution is
>   created in the Horadric Cube by cubing together four different
>   Essences that drop infrequently from the act bosses in Hell
>   difficulty.
>
> The Essences include:
>
> - Twisted Essence of Suffering (dropped by Andariel and Duriel)
> - Charged Essence of Hatred (dropped by Mephisto)
> - Burning Essence of Terror (dropped by Diablo)
> - Festering Essence of Destruction (dropped    by Baal).
>
> They create:  Token of Absolution

source: [Diablo 2 Wikia](http://www.diablowiki.com/Token_of_Absolution_%28Diablo_II%29)